# Bash do while loop to check VPN connection with nmcli in Fedora 30

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, fedora, networkmanager

I'm writing my first bash script to check if a vpn is connected using nmcli, but it still won't recognize a disconnection.

It's pretty simple:

```
PIAUUID="e53d9304-bde2-40e1-8f57-a3fa7115a383"

nmcli con up $PIAUUID

while [ "true" ]
  do
    if [[ $(nmcli con | grep -m 1 "$PIAUUID" | cut -b 26-61) != $PIAUUID ]]; then
            printf  "Disconnected at $(date +'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S') trying to reconnect"
            (sleep 1s && nmcli con up $PIAUUID)
    else
            echo "Connected - checked at $(date +'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S')"
    fi
    sleep 30
done > monitor.log
```

All the variables, connection info, etc. are contained in an external file.  This do-while loop is only supposed make sure the UUID obtained from nmcli is the same as the one supplied to identify the connection parameter file.

The presumption is if they are not the same, nmcli will not be connected to the VPN and it will try to re-connect.

But if I run the script and then disconnect from the VPN while it's running, it doesn't recognize it.  So something in the way that it's testing the two UUIDs for equality isn't working.

Comment: why do you have parens around `sleep 1 && nmcli ...` Doing so runs in your command in a sub shell that doesn't help, and just adds noise to trying to debug your problem. Maybe you want to run the `nmcli ..` portion in the background, and if so, then append an `&` at the end of that cmd. AND you need to confirm that your code is working as you intend. Add `set -vx` near the top of your script and make sure your variable values and comparisons are actually working with the data as you expect. Good luck.

Comment: Do you use openvpn or something else?
I guess adding the VPN type is a useful tag